# HELP! I tried to render some objects, but the result is only black!

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, camera

I want to render 2 object, in the rendered preview it looks fine
[image: This looks fine, and what I want]

butwhen I press F12 the result is only a black screen like this
[image: This is the problem]

I have switched the little camera icon in the left on, btw I deliberately switch off camera in object 'Plane' that I don't want to render,

If you want to help me please download this blender file, thanks http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50853

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with your file, all three planes seem to be rendering. Maybe you can find something in the linked questionl.